# How to apply custom retry policy to Eventhub binding in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

My project is using Azure Eventhub binding as IAsyncCollector.
Follow the source code, Azure function will use default retry: 
Exponential Retry with: MaxTimeout = 30 second, RetryCount= 9.

I want to increase MaxTimeout and RetryCount but I cannot found anyway to change retry policy if IAsyncCollector.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems feature to apply a custom retry policy for Azure Eventhub binding isn't available yet.

Please take a look at this issue started by a Microsoft Member on GitHub

[Provide a configurable retry policy for event hub triggered functions #1597](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1597)

In absence of a custom retry policy, you could write your own logic to catch relevant exceptions and re-process/retry failed messages further. This could help with your increase the retry count requirement (although it will take longer to retry this way).

Comment: Thank you for information I just want to make sure there is no way except write catch block. Hope Azure will integrate custom policy in binding soon